# Prove that if $a \equiv b \pmod m$, then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a  \equiv b \pmod m$, then $a^2 \equiv b^2  \pmod m$.

I have started with the definition of congruence and need advice on where to go from here.

Comment: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: We need to show that $m$ divides $a^2-b^2$. We are told that $m$ divides $a-b$. So $a-b=mt$ for some integer $t$. It follows from the factorization above that $a^2-b^2=m(t(a+b))$, so $m$ divides $a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$a \equiv b \pmod m \Leftrightarrow m|a-b \Rightarrow m|(a-b)(a+b) \Rightarrow m|a^2-b^2 \Leftrightarrow a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod m$$

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different route:

$$a=km+r \Rightarrow a^2=k^2m^2+2rkm+r^2\equiv_m r^2$$

$$b=lm+r \Rightarrow b^2=l^2m^2+2rlm+r^2\equiv_m r^2$$

Same reminders modulo $m$, hence $a^2\equiv_m b^2$.